# PROPERTYKEY::pid Meaning

Tags: winapi, windows-7, ipropertystorage

Can someone explain what the `pid` field in a [`PROPERTYKEY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773381.aspx) structure is? Microsoft says just don't use `0` or `1` and you're fine, but this doesn't help when I need to implement `IPropertyStore` in my code. Is the `pid` supposed to be part of the key, so multiple values with the same `fmtid` but different `pid` may be present? Or should it be ignored, so `GetValue` should return any value with a matching `fmtid`, ignoring `pid`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fmtid+pid combination is historically related to OLE (yes, that's pretty old).

At that time, the `fmtid` (format id) was like a category, and the pid (property id) was the property identifier in the category. For example, you have here the first FMTID defined: [Predefined Property Set Format Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). These properties are still used for Office documents (Author, Keywords, etc.) So you had many properties per category (so few fmtid for a lot of properties), but the combination of both fmtid and pid always make the property unique across space and galaxies.

Others FMTID appeared since, you can have a look at in in Windows SDK's propkey.h: FMTID_AudioSummaryInformation, FMTID_Volume, FMTID_ShellDetails, etc...

Today, for some new properties, the FMTID does not mean anything anymore. For example, the [System.Contact.Birthday](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/bb787596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a fmtid of 1`76DC63C-2688-4E89-8143-A347800F25E9` and an id of `47`, but the fmtid has no special meaning, and is not defined specifically, so it in fact could be used solely for the key.

So, for a given property, you must consider the key is still the combination of both (hence the structure name: PROPERTYKEY), but you could define your own properties with pid as something greater or equal to 2 (as the official doc specifies) and fmtid as a new guid if you prefer. I personally still prefer to define one common FMTID for a group of properties.

Comment: Don't use pid zero or one not even for custom fmtids.

Comment: @RaymondChen - PROPERTYKEY reference doc indeed stipulates the value must be greater or equal to 2. These are PID_DICTIONARY & PID_CODEPAGE right? I knew these have special meaning for OLE compound storage but is it still forbidden even if not used in compound files?

Comment: Reserved pids are reserved.

Comment: Thanks @Simon especially about your ideas on the reserved PID's very interesting!!!